# How to calculate inverse Laplace of this response function?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, laplace-transform

Sorry for my English in terms of control theory - up to now I used only German phrases in that field.

There is a controlled process of order 2 with

$$F_p(s)=\frac{1}{(1+s)^2} $$

which shall be controlled in "standard-form" by the controller of type I

$$F_c(s)=\frac{1}{sT} $$

The total transfer function from setpoint to output is
$$F(s)=\frac{F_p F_c}{1+F_p F_c} = \frac{1}{sT(1+s)^2+1}$$

How do I get the time-function at the output, when a step-function is applied at the input?

I cannot manage to get the complex roots of the denominator:

$$sT(1+s)^2+1 = K(s-s_1)(s-s_2)(s-s_3)$$

The original question was:

```
How to choose T, so that the system is right on the edge of a swing-over (aperiodic limiting case) behavior.
```

I have no Idea, how to solve this analytically.

By using Wolfram alpha

[image]

I found roots, but there are two are complex conjugated roots and one real one. The analytic representation is quite awful, but, anyway, there are complex solutions. Each complex solution gives rise to a damped oscillation, so how can it be, that T can be chosen at all to yield no overswing (see image of inverse Laplace)? BTW: By simulation of the closed loop I'm convinced, that there IS a limit for T to yield aperiodic behavior.

[image]

Comment: Partial fractions allows you to break down the formula into smaller easier bits to solve.

Comment: What did you mean with "*right on the edge of a swing-over (aperiodic limiting case) behavior*"? That it should be similar to a 2nd order, critically damped (e.g. not under damped, not over damped)? Like a Bessel filter?

Comment: I mean critically damped. I found the solution and posted it here as an answer. My English expressions for control engineering are poor...

Comment: @Andy aka: But for partial fraction decomposition one must know the roots of the denominator...How would you do it in particular for my example?

Comment: @MichaelW Now it makes sense. I'm also not a native English speaker, so the chances that I might get the meaning wrong are increased...

Comment: It was not quite obvious for me, that immediately before we get a complex root there is a two-fold real root. It became finally clear by viewing the graph in the real plane: There is no other possibility...By using the general solution I got from Wolfram Alpha I was quite shocked and, moreover, it seamed from there, that there are always two conjugate complex poles. However, this is not true... spent hours on that...

Comment: Yes, when critically damped there is an overlapping dual pole. As more damping occurs, the poles separate along the sigma axis and remain 0 on the jw axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: I think the solution is as follows (it took me incredible long to find it out, although the problem seems quite simple):

Assuming to be at the edge of just having no complex solution, there must be one double root and one single root:

So the ansatz is:

$$Ts(1+s)^2+1 = T(1+s_1)^2(1+s_2)$$

This gives by coefficient comparison

$$s_1=1/3, s_2=4/3, T=27/4$$

So the transfer function for just having no overswing is

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{\frac{27}{4}s(1+s)^2+1}$$

and the I-control is

$$F_c(s) = \frac{4}{27}\cdot \frac{1}{s}$$

The simulation is excatly as expected:

The parameter is

$$K_I = 1/T$$

showing the behavior at the boundary. The limit for T is 27/4, a slightly smaller value gives rise to overswing.

[image]

Comment: If this is the answer you're looking for then you can select it with the check mark.

Comment: Is my own answer. It cannot be checked by yourself.

Comment: I didn't mean the voting (the up or down arrows), I meant the green check mark right beneath them. You are well entitled to select your own answer.